# pyautocad - Block reference Custom Tab

Tags: python, autocad

I have successfully inserted the Block and changed the attributes. Now I want make changes in the Custom Tab. I am not able to find any way to edit this custom tab using pyautocad. If any one knows please help me out. I have attached the image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Custom` section of the AutoCAD Properties Palette for a Block Reference generally refers to the set of Dynamic Block Parameters.

Since pyautocad looks to use the ActiveX COM interface, you should be able to access these parameters by iterating over the collection returned by the [`getdynamicblockproperties`](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/idh_getdynamicblockproperties.htm) method, and retrieving the [`PropertyName`](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/idh_propertyname.htm) and [`Value`](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/idh_value.htm) properties of each [`DynamicBlockReferenceProperty`](http://entercad.ru/acadauto.en/idh_dynamicblockreferenceproperty_object.htm) object within this collection.